# How to create a numbered list across cells in jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter

I need to create a list of questions in a jupyter notebook. Ideally I would write something like `Q#. bla bla` in one cell, `Q#. bla bla` in another cell, and they would be numbered correctly. Is that doable? Many thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may achieve what you are looking for, but it is not as clean as using straight markdown.  You can initialize `q=0` and then put python code inside double braces `{{ }}` in your markdown cells, so something like:

```
{{q=q+1}}
Q{{ q }}: Hello World?
```

BUT, these can get muddled if you don't run your markdown in order.

You could also use [display_markdown](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.display_markdown), but you will have your question show up below the code cell.

**Update:**
You could use the [incremental feature of CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-increment) to generate the numbers for your questions.  BUT, you would need to either:

1. Include the CSS in the first cell of the notebook, which is easy but very visible and would need to be executed by the user
2. Reference the an external style somehow, which might be complicated if you're sending this to other users.

For the first case you would have the following in your first cell using [html magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-html):

```html
%%html
<style>
body {counter-reset: q-counter;}

h1::before {
  counter-increment: q-counter;
  content: "Question " counter(q-counter) ". ";
}
</style>
```

and then for each markdown question cell you would use `h1` tag (`h2`, `h3`, etc could also be used, just update the CSS accordingly), so something like:

```
<h1>Hello World?</h1>
```

Then the following markdown cells:

[image]

Would look like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Two things: (i) The [Python Markdown](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/python-markdown/readme.html) extension needs to be installed; (ii) `Q{{q+=1;q}}` works as well. Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is not so satisfying, notably because (i) when I clean the notebooks and send them to students, the question numbers do not show until the cells have been executed; and (ii) students need to manually trust the notebooks. I hope to find a better solution. Thanks anyway jayvesea!